# How to have 2 same functions in Javascript for 3 different images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

**The following is code that I found online from someone and used it in my own code:**

```
var image=new Array("/Users/ghanimbakhit/Desktop/HTML Project/images/rock.jpg",
"/Users/ghanimbakhit/Desktop/HTML Project/images/rock2.jpg",
"/Users/ghanimbakhit/Desktop/HTML Project/images/rock3.jpg");


var timeout={};
function stopIt(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
function changeimage(dvX){
    var dvi=document.getElementById(dvX);
    if(!dvi.count || dvi.count == image.length )
    dvi.count=0;
    dvi.src=image[dvi.count];
    dvi.alt=image[dvi.count];
    dvi.count=dvi.count+1;
    timeout=setTimeout('changeimage("'+dvX+'")',3500);
}
```

**The following is the HTML code:**

```
<body onload="changeimage('changer')">
<div style="position:absolute;top: 600px"  ><img width="350" src="t1 alt="Rock Climbing"  id="changer"/></div>
</body>
```

#### This code is used to automatically change between images every few seconds. I have changed the images to "rock", "rock2", and "rock3". I have 2 more images that I want to add. How can I do that without overriding the above code? I'm new to JavaScript.

If you need anymore information, please notify me. I have to submit this in 3 hours. Thank you!

UPDATE:  I need the same function elsewhere for 2 different images separately aligned and placed in the HTML code. Meaning I want THIS function to work for other images in the webpage.

Comment: Just add links to the two images you want inside the `image` array at the top.

Comment: No it's not that, let me be more specific.
I need the same function elsewhere for 2 different images separately aligned and placed in the HTML code.

Comment: Oh...That makes more sense! Thanks. I'll make a code snippet of how to do that.

Comment: What specifically are you asking?  Your question states that you want to add 2 more images to the function, which Noble correctly states, just add it to the array instantiation at the the top.  Your Update, however, indicates that you want to use this function somewhere else, with different images.  In that case, this should all just be wrapped in a function and the images could be passed in as parameters, or a variety of other techniques.  Either way, these answers could be find, simply, elsewhere in SO or via Google.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry if I didn't know how to explain it and I looked for it in Google and I couldn't find it. The part that I told Noble was correct is using this function somewhere else with different images. As you mentioned I don't know how to do that I'm new to Javascript, sorry about my unprofessionalism but I'll try to keep it simple.

Comment: Not trying to get down on your or anything, we all have to start somewhere at some point.  The problem is more that your question is too broad.  This is how it reads: "I have this code I found and don't fully understand.  I would like to use it in other places, with other variables, how can I do that?  Also I need to know within 3hrs, thanks!"  A better approach would be: "I have this HTML that uses this function.  I have another set of HTML, on this page/div/etc., that I would like to also use this function and using this data (a,b,c).  Does that make sense?  The question should be focused.

Comment: Additionally, giving us what you tried helps us know where your misunderstandings might be, or where there might be a bug/flaw in the code or system.

Comment: My bad, I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply add a parameter for which image set to use with which image like this http://jsfiddle.net/zxmbbc31/1/

HTML:

```
<body onload="changeimage('changer', image); changeimage('changer2', image2); changeimage('changer3', image3)">
     <div style="position:absolute;top: 600px"  >
          <img width="350" src="t1" alt="Rock Climbing"  id="changer"/>
          <img width="350" src="t1" alt="Rock Climbing"  id="changer2"/>
         <img width="350" src="t1" alt="Rock Climbing"  id="changer3"/>
      </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
  var image=new Array("/rock.jpg","/images/rock2.jpg", "rock3.jpg");
  var image2=new Array("/Users//rock.jpg","/rock2.jpg","images/rock3.jpg");
  var image3=new Array("Project/images/rock.jpg","rock2.jpg","rock3.jpg");

 var timeout={};
 function stopIt(){
 clearTimeout(timeout);
}
function changeimage(dvX, images){
    var dvi=document.getElementById(dvX);
    if(!dvi.count || dvi.count == images.length )
    dvi.count=0;
    dvi.src=images[dvi.count];
    dvi.alt=images[dvi.count];
    dvi.count=dvi.count+1;
    timeout=setTimeout('changeimage("'+dvX+',' +images+")',3500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, mostly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to apply it but, the images don't change now.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, have two different arrays and two different `<img>` elements for each set of images you want to alternate. Then, call the `changeImage()` function twice with both arrays and `<img>` elements.

```js
//We have two different arrays within an array for two different sets.
var images = [["http://www.mspaintadventures.com/images/v3_banner2_store1.gif", "http://blog.codinghorror.com/assets/images/favicon.ico?v=bdb986f48f", "http://www.mspaintadventures.com/images/v3_banner_store2.gif"], ["http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/polyglot-404.png", "http://www.mspaintadventures.com/images/PSbooktwobanner.gif"]];


//We have two different timeouts for two different sets.
var timeouts = [null, null];
function stopIt(i){
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
function changeimage(id, i){
    //We pass in both the id and the images
    //because both of these will change in our function calls.
    var image = images[i];
     console.log(image);
    var dvi=document.getElementById(id);
    if(!dvi.count || dvi.count == image.length )
        dvi.count=0;
    dvi.src=image[dvi.count];
    dvi.alt=image[dvi.count];
    dvi.count=dvi.count+1;
    //We use a function instead of a string
    //because using a string with setTimeout() is _always_ a bad idea.
    timeouts[i] = setTimeout(function() {
        changeimage(id, i)
    }, 3500);
}

//It is a much better idea to put the event in JavaScript instead of inline HTML
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    changeimage("changer1", 0);
    changeimage("changer2", 1);
});
```

```html
<!-- We do not set the src attributes of the images
     because we will set them in JavaScript-->
<img width="350" alt="Rock Climbing" id="changer1"/>
<img width="350" alt="Rock Climbing" id="changer2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function call inside another function. I called it init in the example. Then you can call changeimage for all of your images inside init.

```
var image = [
    "/Users/ghanimbakhit/Desktop/HTML Project/images/rock.jpg",
    "/Users/ghanimbakhit/Desktop/HTML Project/images/rock2.jpg",
    "/Users/ghanimbakhit/Desktop/HTML Project/images/rock3.jpg"
];


var timeout = {};

function stopIt () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function changeimage (dvX) {
    var dvi = document.getElementById(dvX);

    if(dvi.count === undefined || dvi.count == image.length ) {
        dvi.count = 0;
    }

    dvi.src = image[dvi.count];
    dvi.alt = image[dvi.count];
    dvi.count = dvi.count + 1;

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        changeimage(dvX);
    }, 3500);
}

function init () {
    changeimage('changer');
    changeimage('changer2');
    changeimage('changer3');
}
```

Then for your HMTL:

```
<body onload="init()">
```